# Switch user from root to another user in MySQL through command line

Tags: mysql, database

I installed MySQL database in my machine. I was new to MySQL, can anyone help me with query used to switch to another user in MySQL through command line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have posted an answer, check out hopefully it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

It's an easy step, you can simply use the "system mysql -uvivek -p" from "mysql" CLI.

**Logging into first your:**

```
[vivek@centosnode1 ~]$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 

mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

**Logging into different user within mysql CLI**

```
mysql> system mysql -uvivek -p
Enter password: 

mysql> select user();
+-----------------+
| user()          |
+-----------------+
| vivek@localhost |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Let us know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing this command on mysql directory.

```
mysql -u yourusername -p
```

After pressing enter it'll ask for the password and you're in.

Happy Coding.